# Mongoid sort on array with days, ignore sunday(0)

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm storing day numbers 0-6 in an array on a document.

I want the documents to always be in the correct order but sunday(0) is making that troublesome since it will be before monday(1). How could I make this ordering in another way?

```
default_scope asc(:days)
```

**Update:**

So when trying to implement a custom serialization I ran into a problem:

```
class Schedule
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :days, type: Days  
  default_scope order_by([[:days, :asc]])
end  

class Days
  include Mongoid::Fields::Serializable

  # Convert Ruby wday format, sunday(0) - saturday(6).
  def deserialize(days)
    days.map { |day| (day + 1)%7 }
  end

  # Convert to MongoDB friendly format, monday(0) - sunday(6).
  def serialize(days)
    days.map { |day| (day + 6)%7 }
  end
end
```

So far so good, the custom field serialization works as expected:

```
s2 = Schedule.create(days: [0])
s.days 
# Deserialized value => [0]
s.read_attribute :days
# Stored value => [6]
```

However, Mongoid seems to sort on the deserialized object?

```
s2 = Schedule.create(days: [1,2,3,4,5])
s2.days
# Deserialized value => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
s2.read_attribute :days
# Stored value => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 

Schedule.all
# Sorted as => [s1, s2]
# Expected sort order => [s2, s1]
```

Confirmed by removing the deserialization, that will return the documents in the correct order. It might be worth noting that this is an embedded document, I guess maybe the ordering is done in a different way.

**Update 2:**
I ended up creating a second field, sortable_days, which I used the serializer on, but not the deserializer, and then sorted on that field instead.

Comment: why not change your model of the days and go from monday (0) to sunday (6) or monday (1) to sunday (7) ?

Comment: Well, I could, but I'd like to keep it consistent with ruby's wday.

Comment: I could, however, write a custom Mongoid serializer/deserializer that takes care of that and store it "monday (0) to sunday (6)" anyways, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: But why do you have to store `wday` in db separately? Probably if you store entire date, it will be anyway sorted correctly.

Comment: Ah, @NIA it's for a weekly opening scheme, so each model represents the opening hours for one or more days, hence, the array of days. It's not coupled to dates so that's why I'm not storing them. [here's the reasoning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375799/schema-for-opening-hours-mongodb)

Comment: @Yeggeps, oh, I see... Hmm, maybe you can store wdays as dates with some fake month/year value but it is definitely **not** cleaner as serializer/deserializer, so sorry.

Comment: Thanks @NIA, might go for that solution or Winfield's.

Comment: Btw, to get "monday(0) to sunday(6)" in one line without `if`s you can do `my_wday = (wday + 6)%7`. And inverse (to get back to Ruby wday) — `wday = (my_wday + 1)%7`

Comment: Maybe Ruby's `date#cwday` is useful. It goes from [1 (monday) to 7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cwday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB only allows sorting on a field for forward/reverse values.  By using 0 for sunday, there's no way to preserve the ordering for 1-6 but put 0 at the end.  In Postgres or other SQL servers you could use a custom sort function to achieve this, but there is no analogue in MongoDB.

You will need to change your value encoding for this.  You could create a denormalize version of this value that has the transformed (0 => 7) value for this field and sort on this field.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about that, that's a possible solution. However as I don't actually care about the stored values I guess a serializer/deserializer solution would be a little bit cleaner, thanks!