# How to store HourTime parameter with mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store Documents with HourTime parameter.
The requirement is to be store HourTime of opening hour of supermarket and I need the option to query "Which supermarket is open now"?

what the best practice to do that and how to develop it?
I use nodejs, express and mongoose.
thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314666/how-to-properly-design-working-hour-schema-for-restaurants-on-mongodb or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375799/schema-for-opening-hours-mongodb and some rather poor examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033367/check-if-current-date-between-two-dates-in-french-mongodb-aggregation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648337/mongodb-aggregate-query-to-compare-time-in-string-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hour and minute. First you need to create the fields, if you have multiple times depending on week day you can also use an array.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("600631c7c8eb4369cf6ad9c8"),
    name: "Market X",
    openHour: 10, // number between 0 and 23
    openMinute: 30 // number between 0 and 59,
    closeHour: 18, // number between 0 and 23,
    closeMinute: 30, // number between 0 and 59
    weekDay: 1 // number beetween 1 and 7 
}
```

With a model like this you can do a find:

```
{
  weekDay: 1, // number between 1 (Monday) and 7 (Sunday)
  openHour: { $lte: 11 }, // number between 0 and 23
  openMinute: { $lte: 32 }, // number between 0 and 59
  closeHour: { $gte: 17 }, // number between 0 and 23
  closeMinute: { $gte: 20 } // number between 0 and 59
}
```

The params for the query in find you can achieve using time with day.js, for example `dayjs().format("HH")` will retrieve the actual hour where your node is running.

Comment: I would suggest to use ISO-8601 standard, i.e. first day of week (1) is Monday, not Sunday. This will make comparison easier. As you see in [$dateFromParts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/), [$dateFromString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) or [$dateToParts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) the native functions always use weekday according to ISO-8601

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i used Sunday as the first day in reason of $dayOfWeek return this way, i will edit with the ISO-8601 standard